# AS3, Load the last text file from a directory

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this function that loads an specific .log file:

```
function loadTracks():void {
tracksLoader.load(new URLRequest("/Users/Me/127.0.0.1,"+_logNum+".log")); 
}
```

The logNum variable gets its value, writing it by hand in a separate text file, avoiding to open and editing the .fla each time the new .log has a different name:

```
logNumLoader.load(new URLRequest("/Users/Me/trackLogNum.txt"));
```

So this is my question:

Some application creates in each session a new .log file with this file name pattern:

**127.0.0.1,NUMBER.log** // Being NUMBER the 5 digit changing part of the name, each time a new .log file is created. The newer the file, the higher this value is.

I would like to know how to make this script to autoload the last .log file, as it has the highest value in its name.

I.E.

Having in /Users/ME/

127.0.0.1,12345.log

127.0.0.1,34567.log

127.0.0.1,56789.log

In this case, the script must automatically select and load the 127.0.0.1,56789.log file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PHP to either identify the latest log by using the filemtime function or by sorting the log files ( following your description , the highest log should come last ).

Edit:
This can't be done in Actionscript 3, unless it's an Air application. AS3 deals with the client site and accessing files & directories is a server side operation.

I'm not a PHP guru so , although I could offer a solution that works fine, it would take me more time and might not be as efficient as what some of the PHP stars here could come up with. I would recommend you to either retag your question or simply post a new question asking what script you actually need to sort out your log files.

When you have the PHP script, look at the following tutorial to see how you can load PHP result into your Flash application. In this example , the script retrieves value from a database, but you should be able to easily adapt this to your context , as long as the script returns content in the form of a name/value pair. It's all explained in the tutorial ;)
http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/loadingAS3/loadingData.php?page=5

Comment: Hi, could it be done in actionscript inside the same .fla, instead in php? If could´t and if it is not hard for you, could you show me that specific code or at least an approach in php? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi PatrickS,thank you again for your new answer. About accessing files from AS3, in this case, it´s a local application. I am able to access the text file previously specified, so I think this wouldn´t be a problem to sort the files in AS3, if there is any way to do that. The problem would be to make in PHP, due there is no server running, the .swf is directly stored in a local directory. Thank you again.

Comment: To make it work in AS3, you need to access the content of your local directory in order to get a list of all the files. As soon as you can get this list in AS3, it should be easy to find the latest log. Since this is not an AIR application, I don't know of any method that would return a list of a directory content.

Comment: I have found that you can browse local files from a .swf in local, take a look here http://www.emanuelz.com.mx/blog/browsing-and-loading-local-files-using-filereference-class-54

Comment: This can only be done with user interaction. Calling the browse() method opens up a window where the user can effectively browse thru the local directory , this doesn't seem to apply to your question though...